# Clear Unity Add manifests to package Debug.Log (Google)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYGw1.png)

These logs have occurred since Unity Google Packages were imported

Can you tell me how to turn off these logs?

Clicking log does not link to IDE

Comment: Why do you need that? 
They are editor only logs anyways.

Comment: Every time I play for a test,
Because it makes the console log dirty ;(